# Rust wasm: When is it legal to call JS new X() on a Rust X::new() annotated with wasm_bindgen(constructor)?

Tags: rust, rust-wasm, wasm-pack

Given the following (simplified) Rust code:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen(js_name = MyClass)]
pub struct MyClassJs {
    my_struct: MyStruct,
}

#[wasm_bindgen(js_class = MyClass)]
impl MyClassJs {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub async fn new() -> Result<MyClassJs, JsValue> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Compiled using `wasm-pack`, and this recommendation from the [wasm-bindgen](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/hello-world.html) book:

```js
// Note that a dynamic `import` statement here is required due to
// webpack/webpack#6615, but in theory `import { greet } from './pkg';`
// will work here one day as well!
const rust = import('./pkg');

rust
  .then(m => m.greet('World!'))
  .catch(console.error);
```

The previous statement makes me believe that doing any rust-wasm related calls are illegal until the Promise has resolved.

Which poses the question: which of these statements is true?

1. Is it legal to call `new MyClassJs()` at any time (even before the Promise is resolved)?
2. Is it legal to call `new MyClassJs()` only after the Promise is resolved (but anywhere, including outside the `then` callback?
3. Is it legal to call `new MyClassJs()` only inside the `then` callback?

I have tried finding an answer using these resources, but have found them to not contain the answer to my question:

- https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/
- https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-pack/
- https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/

Edit: I am currently on webpack 4.

Comment: How do you expect to ever access `MyClassJs` before the promise resolves? It doesn't exist in global scope, AFAIK.

Comment: @Cerberus rust-wasm / wasm-pack exports TypeScript definitions that are accessible without waiting for the module to load. I think the point I'm trying to make is that without webpack 5 wasm_bindgen(constructor) is kind of weird?